# Cannot Get jQuery UI Date Picker to Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have been trying for days to figure out what isn't working. I have a website on Business Catalyst where I am simply trying to use the jQuery UI datepicker with an input field. I am very new with Java Script and jQuery, and I know this has to be so simple.

Please let me know if you need to see any other parts of the code, as I tried to condense for space saving purposes. Any help will be really appreciated!

Here is the error code I am receiving. The `.datepicker` function simply isn't working. I've verified multiple times that the jQuery is loaded first, then the jQuery UI. I've also verified my jQuery is inside `$(document).ready()`. I've also tried multiple solutions from Stack Overflow with no luck :-(

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is the HTML In my `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="3.0/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="3.0/js/date.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="3.0/jquery-ui/css/overcast/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here is the JavaScript from my `date.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".datePicker").datepicker();
});
```

And finally the HTML for my form

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_5" id="CAT_Custom_5" class="datePicker" />
```

Comment: Okay so the double quotes were defiantly a copy/paste typo. My bad

Comment: You may need to include `jquery-ui.js` before `date.js`. Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/xE98e/

Comment: Great thought @showdev, definitely didn't try that yet.. but no luck. Still receiving the same error.

Comment: You are getting an error with the fiddle I linked?

Comment: I am not receiving an error in fiddle, but when I made the change on my website, it still returned the same error. Any ideas on why it would work in fiddle but not on my website?

Answer (score 0):

double quotes at the end of these 2 scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="3.0/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js""></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="3.0/js/date.js""></script>
```

correct html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="3.0/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="3.0/js/date.js"></script>
```